# rxjs: how to create a stream from a series of callbacks that times out?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Given an API that invokes a series of callbacks, how would I create an observable that emits the values passed to the callback function and terminates when either (a) a timeout elapses, or (b) one value is found that matches a predicate `predicate`? Ideally, while closing out the API resource via some teardown method `close()` on it.

For example:

```js
interface Api {
   on((value: string) => void): void;
   close();

  // ...
}
```

I've got something like this, but I'm not sure if it's actually the correct way to handle this with regards to edge cases, idiomatic rxjs usage, and non-duplication of emission. I also have the desire to return a structure that represents whether or not an item that fulfills the `predicate` has been found, and all of the events that have been raised so far.

```js
     // someone may subscribe to the stream after events take place
     // and we want them to start from the beginning of the stream
     const source$ = new ReplaySubject(); 
     const api = getApi();
     api.on((value) => { subject.next(value); });

     doSomethingThatGeneratesEvents(api);

     const share$ = source$.pipe(
           takeUntil(race(cancel$, interval(timeout))),
           shareReplay());

    // consume values from `share$` until one matches `predicate`, then emit that value and     finish
    const found$ = share$.pipe(
      find(predicate),
      map((x) => x !== undefined),
    );
    // share$.pipe is a pipeline that passes messages from share$ until the timeout ellapses.
    // the next step in the pipe is `find(predicate)` which gets evaluated up until the timeout occurs.
    // the find short circuits waiting for more values

    // resolve found$ and cancel the stream
    const pass = await firstValueFrom(found$);
    cancel$.next();

    const messages = await firstValueFrom(share$.pipe(toArray()));
    api.close();
    return { pass, messages };
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's actually doing the correct thing. It seems wrong to have to manually trigger a cancel subject, and it seems like I should be able to better encapsulate calling `close()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`takeWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile) will emit while a predicate is true. Setting the `inclusive` parameter to true will also emit the last value when the provided predicate is false. Providing a negated predicate and setting `inclusive` to true will cause it to act like `find` while also emitting the previous values.

[`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) combined with [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) will complete after a timeout.

Then to tell if the predicate was passed or if it timed out you can just check the last value.

You can use [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/finalize) for cleanup on completion or error.

```js
  source$
    .pipe(
      takeWhile((v) => !predicate(v), true),
      takeUntil(timer(3000)),
      toArray(),
      map((arr) => {
        const found = predicate(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        return { pass: found, messages: arr };
      }),
      finalize(() => api.close())
    )
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ytbgph?file=index.ts